# MongoDB - How can I use MapReduce to merge a value from one collection into another collection on multiple keys of a second collection?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have two `MongoDB` collections: The first is a collection that includes frequency information for different IDs and is shown (truncated form) below:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : "A1",
        "value" : 19
    },
    {
        "_id" : "A2",
        "value" : 6
    },
    {
        "_id" : "A3",
        "value" : 12
    },
    {
        "_id" : "A4",
        "value" : 8
    },
    {
        "_id" : "A5",
        "value" : 4
    },
    ...
]
```

The second collection is more complex and contains information for each `_id` listed in the first collection (it's called `frequency_collection_id` in the second collection), but `frequency_collection_id` may be inside two lists (`info.details_one`, and `info.details_two`) for each record:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53cfc1d086763c43723abb07"),
        "info" : {
            "status" : "pass",
            "details_one" : [ 
                {
                    "frequency_collection_id" : "A1",
                    "name" : "A1_object_name",
                    "class" : "known"
                }, 
                {
                    "frequency_collection_id" : "A2",
                    "name" : "A2_object_name",
                    "class" : "unknown"
                }
            ],
            "details_two" : [ 
                {
                    "frequency_collection_id" : "A1",
                    "name" : "A1_object_name",
                    "class" : "known"
                }, 
                {
                    "frequency_collection_id" : "A2",
                    "name" : "A2_object_name",
                    "class" : "unknown"
                }
            ],
        }
    }
    ...
]
```

What I'm looking to do, is merge the frequency information (from the first collection) into the second collection, in effect creating a collection that looks like:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53cfc1d086763c43723abb07"),
        "info" : {
            "status" : "pass",
            "details_one" : [ 
                {
                    "frequency_collection_id" : "A1",
                    "name" : "A1_object_name",
                    "class" : "known",
                    **"value" : 19**
                }, 
                {
                    "frequency_collection_id" : "A2",
                    "name" : "A2_object_name",
                    "class" : "unknown",
                    **"value" : 6**
                }
            ],
            "details_two" : [ 
                {
                    "frequency_collection_id" : "A1",
                    "name" : "A1_object_name",
                    "class" : "known",
                    **"value" : 19**
                }, 
                {
                    "frequency_collection_id" : "A2",
                    "name" : "A2_object_name",
                    "class" : "unknown",
                    **"value" : 6**
                }
            ],
        }
    }
    ...
]
```

I know that this should be possible with MongoDB's `MapReduce` functions, but all the examples I've seen are either too minimal for my collection structure, or are answering different questions than I'm looking for.

Does anyone have any pointers? **How can I merge my frequency information (from my first collection) into the records (inside my two lists in each record of the second collection)?**

I know this is more or less a `JOIN`, which `MongoDB` does not support, but from my reading, it looks like this is a prime example of `MapReduce`.

I'm learning Mongo as best I can, so please forgive me if my question is too naive.

Answer (score 1):

Just like all MongoDB operations, a MapReduce always operates only on a single collection and can not obtain info from another one. So you first step needs to be to dump both collections into one. Your documents have different _id's, so it should not be a problem for them to coexist in the same collection.

Then you do a MapReduce where the **map** function `emit`s both kinds of documents for their common `key`, which is their frequency ID.

Your **reduce** function will then receive an array of two documents for each key: the two documents you have received. You then just have to merge these two documents into one. Keep in mind that the reduce-function can receive these two documents in any order. It can also happen that it gets called for a partial result (only one of the two documents) or for an already completed result. You need to handle these cases gracefully! A good implementation could be to create a new object and then iterate the input-documents copying all existing relevant fields with their values to the new object, so the resulting object is an amalgamation of the input documents.